# Missing data in PouchDB using sqlite with Electron

Tags: angular, sqlite, electron, pouchdb

I'm using pouchdb in my angular2 based electron application with pouchdb-adapter-node-websql storing db with sqlite.

```
PouchDBModule.plugin(require('pouchdb-adapter-node-websql'));
let options = {};
options['prefix'] = "_db_";
options['adapter'] = 'websql';
let PouchDB = PouchDBModule.defaults(options);
```

This code is supposed to work every time without issues, actually in my dev environment it never lose data.

But while running the application as production I realice that sometimes after a restart the data is missing. I know pouchdb make versions of data as part of the core, but using other adapters like IndexedDB this is not happening. Any idea?

Comment: What OS are you running your app on? [Rumors](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/does-ios-delete-websql-databases-in-need-of-storage-space/53137) say that iOS might wipe WebSQL dbs when low on storage...

Comment: My dev environment is mac and it works as expected, the issue is being detected over windows, specifically windows seven.